# Paper showing evidence for Callan-Gross Relation

Tags: experimental-physics, quantum-chromodynamics, partons

I am getting ready for a presentation and want to show a plot showing experimental evidence for the Callan-Gross relation. Are there any papers plotting this beyond 1970 across different $Q^2$ or different ranges of Bjorken-$x$? If not, which paper shows the first experimental evidence for this relation?

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0370269381909916?via%3Dihub is from 1981. VIOLATIONS OF THE CALLAN-GROSS RELATION AS A FUNCTION OF X,Q2 FROM QCD
GONZALEZARROYO, A; LOPEZ, C and YNDURAIN, FJ
1981 | PHYSICS LETTERS B 98 (3) , pp.215-219